# Content script not executing on facebook

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "i-Suite",
  "description": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*//facebook.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]

    }
    ]
}
```

and content.js is

```js
console.log("Test")
```

It doesnot even execute once. Others similar questions I have stumbled upon, have user facing problem with running content script for a second time. It works fine first time for them. Whereas, I am not even able to get it running once.

Do I need a listener in background script? If so, which one?

Comment: Typo in the url definition. Should be `"*://facebook.com/*"`, also you might want to add `"*://www.facebook.com/*"`.

Comment: Thanks...solved by adding www.